# How to tell compiler that null can't be contained in the concurrent queue

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nullable-reference-types

Compiler has complaint - see code

```cs
private ConcurrentQueue<RuleContext> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<RuleContext>();

public void Add(RuleContext ruleContext) 
{
    if (ruleContext == null) return;

    _logQueue.Enqueue(ruleContext); 
}

void Do()
{
    while (_logQueue.TryDequeue(out RuleContext ruleCtx)) // <-- converting to non-nullable type
    { ....  }
}
```

now, when I change that to  `TryDequeue(out RuleContext? ruleCtx)` it calms down.

Question. If type is now `RuleContext?`, why in the `while` block I don't get a warning when dereference it like `ruleCtx.HasLogMessages` ??

`HasLogMessages` defined as

```
public bool HasLogMessages {get => true;}
```

Comment: You haven't included enough code for us to know anything.  Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The variable `ruleCtx` is also available outside the scope of the `while` loop where it could be `null`. The compiler knows that and it also knows that within the while loop it cannot possible be `null`, therefore no warning.

Comment: @Mushroomator absolutely great catch! if I declare this like `ConcurrentQueue<RuleContext?>` it changes everything. Thanks for showing me the light

Comment: Determined that with `while (_logQueue.TryDequeue(out RuleContext ruleCtx))` the `ruleCtx` is not available outside `while`. But with `if`, it is available outside of `if` - `if (_logQueue.TryDequeue(out RuleContext ruleCtx)`

Comment: **TO ALL**: my question title is misleading. I understand now why dereferencing `ruleCtx` inside `while` not causing compilation warning. This is my blunder about "what if dereferencing failed"? Only successful dereferencing will take me into `while` block. Hence compiler is all-good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out` parameter of `ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue` [is marked with `[MaybeNullWhen(false)]` attribute](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs,668) (which does make sense because in case of `false` the parameter would be initialized to the default value) and `RuleContext` seems to be a reference type (for value types everything would be fine), hence the complaint. Just change the type to `RuleContext?` or `var` and that's it:

```cs
void Do()
{
    while (_logQueue.TryDequeue(out RuleContext? ruleCtx)) // or out var ruleCtx
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ruleCtx.GetType()); // no warning
    }
}
```

No warning inside the while block is due to the compiler being able to correctly perform static flow analysis for [nullable references types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) in this case (hence we can be inside the while only if `true` is returned and the attribute warns about nulls only in case of `false` being returned, see the [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) article).

Comment: Thanks. I think, I just understood the mechanism of this. -- if `Try` returns `false`, the item will be `null`. But because only when dequeue is success, the code goes into the while block and there, the item will never be `null`. So, this is the explanation. And the compiler seem doing a good job. I just missed to think about variable content with a failed dequeue. .... I also pointed in the question that I fixed it that way, **I just did not understand why it wasn't triggering compiler warning** in the while block

Comment: @T.S. yes, exactly. The out parameter will be initialized to the default value which is `null` for reference types.

Comment: @T.S. added few more links and a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `out` variable needs to be nullable (if we assume `RuleContext` is a reference type), as it's not guaranteed to always contain a value after the call.

Consider this example:

```
RuleContext ruleCtx;
bool didDequeue = _logQueue.TryDequeue(out ruleCtx);

if (didDequeue == false)
{
    // What is the value of 'ruleCtx'?
}
```

Since you can't be sure that `TryDequeue` always dequeue's an item, `ruleCtx` cannot be non-nullable.

Comment: I guess, you have something here. if `Try` returns `false`, the item will be `null`. But because only when dequeue is success, the code goes into the `while` block and there, the item will never be null. So, this is the explanation. And the compiler seem doing a good job. I just missed to think about variable content with a failed dequeue

Comment: What you meant to say, - it is not possible to have `null` in that variable when item is dequeued successfully. Not *"What you're trying to do is not possible"*

Comment: @T.S. You're right, I didn't fully understand the phrasing of the question at first. I've rephrased my answer, so it's clear that it's the part about making it non-nullable that is not possible.

Comment: _"The `out` variable needs to be nullable, "_ - that is not completely true. If the queue stores value types the out variable does not require to be nullable.

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks for that clarification. I've added that this is under the assumption it's a reference type.